# PyCharm cannot debug async tests after update to 2023.3

Tags: pycharm

After I upgraded my Pycharm to 2023.3.3 (Build #PY-233.13763.11, built on January 25, 2024) I cannot debug my async tests anymore.

The debugger dies with

> pycharm AttributeError: 'ProactorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_compute_internal_coro'

I'm using pytest-asyncio==0.23.4 but it seems unrelated to that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- CTRL+Shift+A
- Search for "Registry..."
- Remove the checkmark at `python.debug.asyncio.repl`
- Restart IDE

**Edit**: According to the [bug ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-64542) the problem should be fixed with PyCharm 2023.3.4.

Comment: Corresponding ticket in PyCharm's issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-64542

Comment: this also fixed the error following (likely related) error for me: AttributeError: 'QiProactorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_compute_internal_coro'